# iPhone 12 discord problem

Tags: iphone

yesterday I bought an iPhone 12 and now in my discord it shows this picture. It says i have iPhone 13
Any one know what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 'sales' model number & the 'actual' model number are rarely the same.

The iPhone 12 is actually the 13th iPhone generation.

The numbering has never matched - the first iPhone was the 3, every other year there's 'last year's number' plus S. There was no iPhone 9.  All this adds up to it… not adding up;)

You can check any model [Mac, phone or pad] designation on [Everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/index-iphone-specs.html)